# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).enableButtonGroup is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the jqgrid to work with laravel 5. I followed this tutorial:
http://www.mariogallegos.com/tutorials/crud-custom-form

It seems to work but when I click on the grid then I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).enableButtonGroup is not a function(…).

My code:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/tutorial/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/tutorial/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-v2.0.3/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-ui-v1.10.3/dev/minified/jquery.ui.effect.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-ui-v1.10.3/dev/minified/jquery.ui.effect-shake.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-jqGrid-v4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-jqGrid-v4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-scrollto-v1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap-v3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-jqMgVal-v0.1/jquery.jqMgVal.src.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/tutorial/js/helpers.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/tutorial/js/base.js')}}"></script>


<!-- When a row is clicked the edit and delete button will be enabled. -->
<script type='text/javascript'> 
        $.ajaxSetup({
                 headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            })

            function onSelectRowEvent(rowid, status, e)
                {
                    //"btn-group-2" is the "ID" of the second button group.
                    //The "enableButtonGroup" is a custom helper function, its definition
                    //can be foound in the public/assets/tutorial/js/helpers.js script.
                    $('#btn-group-2').enableButtonGroup();
                }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `helpers.js` is loading properly--no errors?

Comment: How can i see if helper.js is loading correctly?

Comment: i don't see any errors in the consol.log that the helpers.js can't be find

Comment: Check "network tab" in DevTools. Verify `content-type` and `status code` in response header

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm seeing it in de network tab. How do iverifiy content-type and status code. i'm using google chrome

Comment: Request URL:http://ptm.app:8000/assets/tutorial/js/helpers.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 05 Nov 2016 07:12:59 GMT
ETag:"54192668-1094"
Last-Modified:Wed, 17 Sep 2014 06:12:56 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.1

Comment: The status code looks OK, check if `content-type` is `application/javascript` or similar. If it is, then you should be checking the file if it has `enableButtonGroup` function or not

Comment: Where can i find the content-type? The function is indeed in the helpers.js

Comment: the function in helpers.js:/**
 * Enable a group of buttons within a container.
 *
 * @returns void
 */
$.fn.enableButtonGroup = function()
{
 this.find('button').each(function()
 {
  $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
 });
};

Comment: Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127424/discussion-between-adam-azad-and-user3552264).